# Exercises question about concept of Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

For the following two parts question, I want to ask about part b.  The question is as follows:

(a) Let $I$ be an ideal of the commutative ring $R$ and $a\in R$.

Prove that the set $S=\{ar+s\mid r\in R, s\in I\}.$

is an ideal of $R$ contianting $I$.

(b) if $e\in R$ and $a \notin I$, show that $I \subset S$ (an equivalent but different phrasing of this question is that $I \subsetneqq S$)

To do (b), suppose $s \in I$ then since elements of the form $s+ar$ is an element of S for all $r\in R$ and $s\in I$.  Then in particular, $s+0(e)=s \in S$ for $0$ and $e \in R.$ 
  My questions are as follows:

!)I am not sure if I am on the right track.
2) are there concrete examples of this questions and what happens if $a\in S$
3) Lastly, does the symbol mean $\subsetneqq$ not a subset of?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The symbol $\subsetneqq$ means subset but not equal

Comment: @Javi ok, thank you.  :)

Comment: If it helps understanding, given an ideal $I$ and $a\in R$, then $S=(a,I)$, the ideal generated by $a$ and $I$. For example, take $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ and $I=(x)$, $a=y$. In this case $S=(x,y)$.

Comment: @Javi is my solution correct, can I ask?

Comment: I don't understand the role of $e$ in the question so I'm not sure if I can give you an answer. I mean, $S$ is defined from $a$ and $I$, does $e$ generate $I$?

Comment: @Javi $e$ denotes the identity.  I am not sure why $R$ needs to contain the identity for it to hold.

Comment: Even if $R$ does not contain $e$, it is true that $I\subseteq S$ since for any $s$ in $I$ you can take $r=0$ and then $a0+s=s\in S$. I think you need $e$ to show that $I\neq S$. If $e\in R$ and take $s=0$, then $ae+0=a\in S$ but $a$ is not in $I$.

Comment: @Javi ah okay okay, that makes compete sense.  Thank you so much.

Comment: If you don't asssume $e\in R$ it could be that $ar\in I$  for all $r$. For example, if your multiplication is defined by $xy=0$ for all $x,y\in R$ (this is call a square zero rng), then $ar+s=0+s\in I$ for all $a,r,s$ so $I=S$.

Comment: @Javi so for a square zero ring, from the definition, it means it has zero divisors?

Comment: Every element is a zero divisor by definition, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will summarize the comments in an answer. For b) you have to show that $I\subseteq S$ but $I\neq S$. So let $s\in I$ and $r=0\in R$, then $s=ar+s\in S$, so $I\subseteq S$. To show $I\neq S$, let $s=0$. Since $e\in R$, let $ae+0=a\in R$. Since, by assumpsion $a\notin I$, we get $I\neq S$.

It is necessary to assume that $e\in R$ for the inequality $I\neq R$. For instance, if you multiplication is trivially defined as $xy=0$ for all $x,y\in R$ (also called [square zero rng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)#Examples), we have that $ar+s=s$ for all $a,r,s$, so $I=S$.

Conceptually, the ideal $S$ is $(a,I)$, the ideal generated by $a$ and $I$. For instance, if $I$ is generated by $g_1,\dots, g_n$ then $(a,I)$ is generated by $a,g_1,\dots, g_n$.

Comment: thank you so very much for your detail write up.

Comment: you're welcome, would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: I just click on the check mark on your answer, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, thank you!